# RxSwift bind to formatted value of variable

Tags: ios, swift, viewmodel, rx-swift

Just started learning RxSwift. I feel like there should be a better way for me to do this:

ViewController:

```
viewModel.orderDate.asObservable()
        .bind { [weak self] (date) in
            self?.orderButton.setTitle(viewModel.formattedOrderButtonText, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

ViewModel:

```
var orderDate = Variable<Date?>(nil)
var formattedOrderButtonText: String {
    get
    {
        let date = orderDate.value
        if(date == nil)
        {
            return "String 1"
        }
        else
        {
            return "String 2"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to bind button's title to formatted variable?

Comment: FYI `orderDate` should be a `let` not a `var`.

Answer (score 1):

`Variable` is deprecated and maybe removed in future release so I'd used `Relay` in place of it.

A better approach would be to do the formatting in `map` of the observable sequence and bind to the output.

Something like this in `ViewModel`:

```
var orderDate = BehaviorRelay<Date?>(value: nil)
lazy var formattedOrderButtonText = orderDate.map { return $0 == nil ? "String 1" : "String 2" }
```

And then use `formattedOrderButtonText` in view controller for binding like this:

```
viewModel.formattedOrderButtonText.bind(to: orderButton.rx.title).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to map your variable and then bind it to the button

In the viewModel:

```
let dateTitle: Observable<String> = orderDate.map { date -> String in 
                 return date == nil ? "String 1" : return "String 2"
            }
```

In the view:

```
viewModel.dateTitle.bind(to: orderButton.rx.title).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Also, check to replace Date with a BehaviourSubject or PublishSubject (but I am sure you can do it without storing any data in the ViewModel) I mean if you are storing date in the ViewModel you are losing the big part of RxSwift.

Check this [repository](https://github.com/sergdort/CleanArchitectureRxSwift), it shows how to use RxSwift in the right way:

Comment: How about`Predicates`? I'm sure we won't want to handle `nil` values at all. Or `FlatMaps`

Comment: @Dennis Im handling nil values because he is doing it, I mean I have done what he is doing but in a cleaner way, the business logic might want to show "String 1" in the button when it is ni. Also flatmap doesn't makes sense here, you wanted to say compactmap or use .filter. Flatmaps makes sense when you need to do another subscription inside the map, if you just want to parse an item you should use map

Comment: oh yea, `ConcatMap`.. `FlatMap` is deprecated. My bad!

Comment: Btw, I wasn't really questioning your answer though :)

Comment: @Dennis hahaha don't worry, also I could have been doing it wrong! :)  But be careful if the flatmap of RxSwift because it is different from the flatmap of swift (that now is compactMap)

Comment: I’ll take care of that. Thanks :)